# How to send and receive query string sent via anchor tag from one page to another

Tags: php, html

I have this piece of code:

```
<a href="update_product.php?product_id='<?php echo $product_id; ?>'">Update Product Info</a><br><br>
```

I want to send `product_id=<?php echo $productid;?>` to another page-`update_product.php`.

Comment: You are... as a url parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You are already sending it as an url parameter, as said by Mooseman.

To retrieve it in your `update_product.php` page, you can do this :

```
$query_string = isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '';
```

If you only want the product_id :

```
$product_id= isset($_GET['product_id']) ? $_GET['product_id'] : '';
```